# Звук нового сообщения в чате FireBase DataBase

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview.adapter

Ребят,такой вопрос: есть ли какая-то возможность,установить звук при появлении новой записи в RecyclerView(в моем случае это сообщение).
Была попытка прикрутить все это дело к появлению нового элемента на экране,но звук так же появляется просто при скроллинге переписки(чего и следовало ожидать).Все это дело завязано на FireBaseRecyclerAdapter.

```
   canPlaySound = false;// разрешено ли воспроизводить звук

    mFBAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, FirechatMsgViewHolder>(
            ChatMessage.class,
            R.layout.message,
            FirechatMsgViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseReference.child(romName)
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FirechatMsgViewHolder firechatMsgViewHolder, ChatMessage chatMessage, int i) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

            if (chatMessage.getUid().equals(mUid)) {
                firechatMsgViewHolder.setIsSender(true);
            } else {
                firechatMsgViewHolder.setIsSender(false);
            }
            firechatMsgViewHolder.msgText.setText(chatMessage.getText());
            firechatMsgViewHolder.userText.setText(chatMessage.getName());

            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            if (mPhotoUrl.equals("")) {
                mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }
            Glide.with(ChatFragment.this).
                    load(chatMessage.getPhotoUrl()).into(firechatMsgViewHolder.userImage);
            // если при входе в чат все элементы прогруженны - canPlaySound = true;
            if (canPlaySound) {
                sp.play(soundIdShot, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                sp.play(soundIdExplosion, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
    };
    mFBAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            int chatMsgCount = mFBAdapter.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (chatMsgCount - 1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                mMsgRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
            }
        }
    });

    mMsgRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mMsgRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFBAdapter);

    mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName().toString();
    canPlaySound = true;
```

[image: доступные методы для наследования]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете наследоваться от FirebaseRecyclerAdapter и **сделать свой адаптер**.
Как только изменится количество элементов в бОльшую сторону - проигрываете звук.
Для того, чтобы отслеживать такое изменение нужно переопределить **в своём адаптере** метод onDataChanged и создать переменную, которая будет сравнивать имеющееся текущее количество элементов с новым количеством в адаптере

```
int mCurrentItemsCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onDataChanged() {
        super.onDataChanged();
        if (mCurrentItemsCount < getItemCount()) {
            //проигрываем звук
        }
        mCurrentItemsCount = getItemCount();
    }
```

update:
Пример создания своего адаптера, который наследуется от Firebase

```
public class MessageAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessageModel, MessageHolder> {
    int mCurrentItemsCount = 0;

    public MessageAdapter(Query query) {
        super(MessageModel.class, R.layout.item_list, MessageHolder.class, query);
    }


    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(MessageHolder viewHolder,
                                      MessageModel model, int position) {
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDataChanged() {
        super.onDataChanged();
        if (mCurrentItemsCount < getItemCount()) {
            //проигрываем звук
        }
        mCurrentItemsCount = getItemCount();
    }
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = databaseReference.child("messages")
                .limitToFirst(1000).orderByKey();

        MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(query);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Не совсем ясно что вы имеете ввиду. т.е. метод onDataChanged я могу получить только при обращении к databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() и т.д.  В FirebaseRecyclerAdapter я данный метод не нашел..(

Comment: Вам нужно создать свой адаптер, который будет наследоваться от Firebase. Тогда вы получите доступ к переопределяемым методам.
Типа вот такого -> public class MessageAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessageModel, MessageHolder> { ... }

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример создания своего адаптера, который наследуется от Firebase.

Comment: не понимаю,что я делаю не так....все таже история. К вопросу приложил скрин со всеми доступными методами для наследования.

Comment: Дмитрий, вы невнимательно читаете. Вы создаёте адаптер напрямую от FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. А вам нужно создать класс, который будет наследоваться от FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. И вот только в своём классе вы сможете делать все эти манипуляции с переопределениями.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо, сейчас буду разбираться!